# What happens if element in std::queue gets popped and has active reference

Tags: c++, stl, queue

Surprisingly code below runs in debug/release mode without any crash. How it's possible ? Am I missing something ?

```
std::queue<int> queue;
queue.emplace(1);
int& a = queue.front();
queue.pop();
std::cout << a << std::endl;
a = 100;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ std::queue::pop() calls destructor. What of pointer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002282/c-stdqueuepop-calls-destructor-what-of-pointer-types)

Comment: Dangling references and pointers are never guaranteed to crash your program, they just *might*. In this case most implementation won't crash because `int` is a trivial type and the underlying `deque` memory is still there. That's part of why dangling bugs are so insidious.

Comment: `int`s aren't actually destroyed by their destructor. The destructor does nothing and the integer hangs around in limbo until something else is given its memory.

Comment: This fragment exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.